# Extend Sidebar to full height as page height changes

Tags: css, height, sidebar

I have a sidebar that is running a switch for a few routes within my site.  One of them is a table, and as it adds rows, it gets longer than the sidebar.

Currently, it is set to display:flex and height:100%

I can get it to fill the page, but how do I make it continue to stretch as the page grows?

```
.sidebar {
  display:flex;
  text-align:left;
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Not enough info, Try `height:100vh;`

Answer (score -1):

If you have a div which houses your whole page. And say it is set to display as block. ( meaning the height will grow as it needs too. )

And you have your sidebar inside of that main div and set to height:100%;

Then it should grow in height with your main div.

Setting height: 100vh; will contain it to the height of the viewport.

If you are adding to the sidebar and want it to grow then try using.

```
.sidebar{
display: block;
min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Alternatively if you just want your sidebar to grow with the main div. You could try

```
.sidebar{
display:block;
height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code:

```
.sidebar
    {
        height: 100vh;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
```